Python logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler is unable to finish its work, becaus the logging file is used by windows system (PID=4)
Issue with Logging Package: File Locking by 'System' Process (PID = 4)
I'm using the logging package in Python, and occasionally the logger fails to perform time-based file rotation at midnight. When I check the Resource Monitor, I see that the process 'System' (PID = 4) has locked my log file (I'm not sure when or for how long this happens).
Is there any way to prevent this file locking? Alternatively, how can I ask the system to release the file handler so my logger can rotate the file as expected?
I know that restart of OS helps, but the restat is not a solution.

It might be related to antivirus scanning - files would be opened (and therefore locked) in order for antivirus scanning to take place. Are you able to disable virus scanning to see if that makes a difference?

@VinaySajip there is not only this one process (one logging file). I run e.g. 10 processes, each one is using logging in its own file, but this happened 3 times in a year not on the same file name. I waited for few day if the system release my file. but after 3-4 days I have to restat the OS.
